# Promtail not scraping logs from within subdirectories

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I'm having issues getting promtail to scrape files from subdirectories.  My filesystem where the logs are stored is structured as follows:

`/var/log/building1logs/logfolder/<serialnumber>/<logname with different file endings>`

I'd like to be able to scrape all files inside every  subdirectory in the logfolder.

Here is my current scrape config:

```
- job_name: myjob
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: mylogs
      __path__: /var/log/building1logs/logfolder/**/*
```

In practice, this only scrapes files that are located at /var/log/building1logs/logfolder - it doesn't dive into any subdirectory located inside logfolder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What was the version of promtail? Was promtail able to expose anything in its internal log?
I tried to re-produce but couldn't. Meaning I was able to fetch logs from all logs from all log files from subdirectories. My __path__ was similiar `__path__: /tmp/mylogs/**/*`. Logs were from `/tmp/mylogs/seriala` and `/tmp/mylogs/serialb`